# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'vector

Tags: python

I am new to python and cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. I know that there is something wrong with my position update, but I can't figure it out. the error message is displayed at the bottom. This is a code for a binary start system. pls help thanks!

```
from __future__ import division
from visual import *
from visual.graph import *


dt=1e-24
k=9e9
AMU=6.67e-27
e=1.6e-19
proton_mass=1*AMU
He_mass=4*AMU
femto=1e-15
b=0*femto
proton_pos=vector(-30*femto,b,0)
He_pos= vector(0,0,0)
q_proton=-e
q_He=2*e
display_size=femto
c=3e8
x_hat=vector(1,0,0)

proton_vel=vector(4e6,0,0)
He_vel=vector(0,0,0)

proton_mom=proton_mass*proton_vel
He_mom=He_mass*He_vel

CM_init = (proton_mass*proton_pos + He_mass*He_pos)/(proton_mass + He_mass)

Lab = display( title='Lab Frame',
               background=color.white)

CM= display( x=0, y=400,
             title= 'Center of Momentum frame',
             background=color.white)

scat_angle = gdisplay(background=color.white, foreground=color.black, x=0, y=450, ytitle="scattered angle (degrees)", xtitle= "impact parameter (fmeter)")



scat_angle_plot=gdots(gdisplay=scat_angle, color=color.red)
scat_angle_plot1=gcurve(gdisplay=scat_angle, color=color.cyan)


proton_= sphere(display= Lab, pos=proton_pos, radius=0.7*display_size, color=color.red)
He=sphere(display= Lab, pos=He_pos, radius=1.3*display_size, color=color.cyan)
#proton.trail= curve(display=Lab, color=color.cyan, thickness=display_size/10)
He.trail=curve(display=Lab, color=color.cyan, thickness=display_size/10)

momentum_scale= display_size*3/(mag(proton_mom))
He_mom_arrow= arrow(display=Lab, pos=He.pos, axis= He_mom*momentum_scale, color=color.red)
proton_mom_arrow= arrow(display=Lab, pos=proton_pos, axis=proton_mom*momentum_scale, color=color.cyan)


impact_par=(0,.0625,.125,.25,0.375,.5,.75,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

for b in impact_par:
    b=b*femto
    proton_pos=vector(-30*femto, b,0)
    He_pos=vector(0,0,0)
    time=0
    proton_vel=vector(0.5*c,0,0)
    He_vel=vector(0,0,0)

    proton_mom=proton_mass*proton_vel
    He_mom=He_mass*He_vel
    #proton.pos=proton_pos
    #He.pos=He_pos
    proton=sphere(display=Lab, pos=proton_pos, radius=0.7*display_size, color=color.cyan)
    proton_pos.trail=curve(display=Lab, color=color.cyan, thickness=display_size/10)

    while time < 3.5e-21:
        rate(1000)
        radius=proton_pos- He_pos
        radius_hat= norm(radius)
        Force_C= k*q_proton*q_He*radius_hat/(mag2(radius))
        proton_mom= proton_mom + (Force_C)*dt
        He_mom= He_mom +(-Force_C)*dt

        proton_pos= proton_pos+ ((proton_mom/proton_mass)/(1+((proton_mom)/(proton_mass*c))^2)**.5)*dt
        He_pos=He_pos+(He_mom/He_mass)*dt
        #proton.trail.append(proton.pos)
        He_mom_arrow.pos= He_pos
        He_mom_arrow.axis= He_mom*momentum_scale
        proton_mom_arrow.pos=proton_pos
        proton_mom_arrow.axis=proton_mom*momentum_scale


        time=time+dt

    cos_angle= dot(x_hat, norm(proton_mom))
    theta= arccos(cos_angle)
    print "theta=", b, theta, theta*180/pi

    scat_angle_plot.plot(pos=(b/femto, theta*180/pi))
    scat_angle_plot1.plot(pos=(b/femto, theta*180/pi))
    #momentumx_plot2.plot(pos=(
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sarahkunkel/Downloads/vp5.part2.py", line 80
    proton_pos= proton_pos+ ((proton_mom/proton_mass)/(1+((proton_mom)/(proton_mass*c))^2)**.5)*dt
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'vector'
```

I know that there is something wrong with the int and vector, but I'm not sure what to change in my code to fix that.

Comment: Is this VPython? The problem is just what the error message says, you are trying to add `vector` and `int` at line 80 of your code, and the `+` operator can't do that.

Comment: From a quick glance, the problem is `(1+((proton_mom)/(proton_mass*c))^2)` at line 80 (the `1+` part), but I could be wrong.